# Update manager generates 404 error while attempting update. Will not update

Tags: 11.10, apt, repository, updates, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

While running update manager in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric Ocelot I receive this list of errors.

```
> W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/main/source/Sources
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/restricted/source/Sources
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/universe/source/Sources
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/multiverse/source/Sources
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.180 80] , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric/partner/source/Sources
> 404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneric/partner/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu/dists/oneric/main/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu/dists/oneric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu/dists/oneric/universe/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
> http:\\\ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu/dists/oneric/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
> 404  Not Found , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been
> ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am a network technician by trade, so confirmation bias told me I needed to check my network connection first.  I kicked off my loving sister's bandwidth hog, checked my bandwidth, and was back to 19.9Mbps through.  Good enough for updates...

Or not.

This error list is being generated verbatim every time I attempt to update.

My package manager informs me that I have not updated my list in 22 days.

(I know my slashes are backwards.  I'm new, so if I try to post my log as it appears in the error box I'm told I'm posting too many links)

***EDIT:***

Well, that was silly.

I just did some prodding on the Ubuntu update servers while I was asking the question and I found my own answer.

I still believe this information may be useful to other users, so I will not delete the question.  Here goes:

The issue here is that someone, somewhere misspelled "Oneiric" in the original hierarchy of directories for the update servers.  Updates worked fine while the misspelling was reflected in the original sources.list file distributed with 11.10, but upon correcting this rather amusing mistake, some admin somewhere blocked some users (like me) from accessing the folders listed at */**oneric**-backports/main*  (since they no longer exist)

replacing **/oneric-backports/main** with **/oneiric-backports/main** in my sources.list should fix this little problem lickety split.

***EDIT #2:***

My manager would like to inform the public that madman2k no longer has data hosted at ppa.launchpad.net, which would account for the 404 from those last few bits of the error.