# Unable to install openjdk7 from terminal

Tags: installation, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)
>   [Update manager generates 404 error while attempting update. Will not update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91006/update-manager-generates-404-error-while-attempting-update-will-not-update)

When i tried to install jdk from following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Following error was displayed:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe

 openjdk-7-jre-lib all 7u7-2.3.2-1ubuntu0.12.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: try update and upgrade then try fix missing

Comment: If your internet is working try updating now.

Comment: as @Anwar said, then maybe as the error tells you `E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Answer (score 0):

Check your Internet connection and run the following commands from terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```